# Excel formulas bogging down

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to use a grouping column in my excel sheet but the code I am using is extremely unwieldy and is beginning to bog down my spreadsheet when I view it, sometimes crashing it.

```
=D20&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("IP",L20:AK20,0))=FALSE,"I.P.",IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Not Started",L20:AK20,0))=FALSE,"NoStart","Zero")) &AP20
```

Which returns a value which looks like "SEC1NoStart41841". Section, a status which runs across multiply fields, and Date. Is there more stream line way to write this bit of code?

Comment: To me, at least, It doesn't look that bad... You could play around with `IFERROR()` rather than `IF(ISERROR())`, but I'm thinking the gains you'd get would be small... If the data doesn't change often, maybe copy / paste-special values and only keep the formula active in one cell to use again when necessary??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the formula works but it just cumbersome to execute and you don't need to recalc often you can turn on Manual calculation. This means that a cell will only be recalculated if you enter into it and press enter to exit or you press the `Calculate Now`/`Calculate Sheet` buttons

[image]